# Action that US embassy takes

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, embassies

Does the US embassy cancel the visa, if the employer complains or requests to cancel the employee US visa applied through their company?

What possible action does the embassy take if such thing happens?

Comment: "employee US visa".. Are we talking about business visa or work visa?

Comment: i have a B1/B2 multiple entry visa

Comment: Is the visa annotated and your company mentioned there?

Comment: No there is no annotation mentioned on my visa.

Comment: If your employer withdraws its support, that eliminates the premise for the trip for which you applied for the visa. (Sorry about all those *for* phrases; I couldn't come up with a better way of putting it in the time I have.) But your multipurpose multiple entry visa indicates that the US has judged you to be a trustworthy traveler *in general,* and your relationship with your employer is presumably only part of that determination. I think it unlikely that they will revoke your visa.

Comment: Very well answered @phoog

Comment: But if the employer makes a false complaint or something,your answer will still remain the same?

Comment: It would depend entirely on what kind of complaint and how well they could back it up. Making a false complaint about something bad enough to get a visa revoked would be a serious matter.